# How to check if a class B extends A during runtime

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-class

In TypeScript/Javscript, how do I check if class B extends class A

```
class A {
  ...
}

class B extends A {
  ...
}

assert(B extends A) // How to do something like this?
```

---

**Answer:**

Couple of ways to do this. Thanks to @Daniel and @AviatorX

```
B.prototype instanceof A        // true
Object.getPrototypeOf(B) === A  // true
Reflect.getPrototypeOf(B) === A // true
```

Not sure whats the most TypeScript idiomatic way to do it or if there are any missing edge cases but worked for my use case

Comment: Are you trying to do this at design time (get a compile-time error if `B extends A` is false before emitting any JS at all) or at runtime (via some JS code)?

Comment: And are we talking about checking if `B`'s prototype chain includes `A`?  Or are we checking if TypeScript's [structural type system](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing) thinks `B extends A`?  These are different (you can have one be true when the other is false)

Comment: you can get name of parent class using `Object.getPrototypeOf(B).` it will return object from which you can get information about parent class of `B`

Comment: If the accepted answer suffices, then this question is really about JavaScript (ES2015+) and not TypeScript per se.  Consider changing the tags.

Comment: @jcalz This type checking is during runtime and not compilation so thank you for differentiating the two cases. I made the edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) to check if the constructor prototype is an instance of `A`:

```
export class A {
}

export class B extends A {
}

console.log(B.prototype instanceof A);
```

Outputs `true` for me.

Comment: B is not an object, it hasn't been instantiated. So that would be false. `(new B() instanceof A)` would however be true but I don't want to instantiate it.

Comment: In that case matching the prototype should work. I have updated my answer